# Usage (and advantages) of await/async with custom threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing some code that does some web requests, manipulate the answers and returns the result to the caller. It seems to me a natural context for async/await.
This is the method I've written:

```
protected async Task<ProcessingResult> ProcessWebPagesAsync(/* args */)
{
    // awaits and other code here
}
```

The caller runs on a thread created specifically to run those requests, and I can't change the implementation at the moment.
My questions are:

- are there advantages of using async/await on threads not coming from the thread pool?
- how do I call my root method from the context of the existing code? (see example)

```
public class MyProcessor : ProcessorBase
{
    public override ProcessingResult ProcessWebPages(/* args */)
    {
        return this.ProcessWebPagesAsync(/* args */).Result;
    }

    protected async Task<ProcessingResult> ProcessWebPages(/* args */)
    {
        // awaits and other code here
    }
}
```

So, `ProcessorBase.ProcessWebPages()` is called on a "dedicated" thread.
Does it really make sense to use async/await here? Do I get benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of using `async/await` with I/O Bound operations is that you can avoid the cost of allocating a dedicated `Thread` which will mainly block waiting for a response to be returned from the network hardware. When you `await`, work is being processed and called back via the IOCP Pool when a response has returned, and you can set where you would like the rest of your method (Continuation) to run on (Threadpool thread, UI Thread, etc..)

I see no special benefit of running your `ProcessorBase.ProcessWebPages` on a dedicated thread. If you can, you should avoid allocating such a thread for your work and use pure `async` instead. I would also suggest sticking to the convention of async method naming and change your methods name to `ProcessorBase.ProcessWebPagesAsync`